# How to parse dates from other timezones that occur during daylight savings switchover using java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, datetime, dst

I ran into an issue while parsing the following date.

```
08 März 2015 02:15:20
```

Code

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.GERMAN);
fmt.setLenient(false);
try {
    System.out.println(fmt.parse("08 März 2015 02:15:20"));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After some investigation, I found out that due to how DST works, 2 AM in my timezone does not exist. Once the clock strikes 1:59 AM, the next time it updates will be 3 AM. I have checked that this is the case with the following dates:

```
"08 März 2015 01:59:59"
"08 März 2015 03:00:00"
```

Both of which can be parsed correctly.

What I want is a date object that correctly interprets the input date exactly as I see it:

```
Mar 8, 2015 at 2:15:20 AM
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you'd use a parser that allowed you to parse date/time values without trying to apply a time zone at all - both `java.time.*` and [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) allow for this, IIRC, and both are much cleaner than `java.util.*`.

However, if you *have* to use `Date`, and you don't know the origin time zone, the safest approach is to use `TimeZone`:

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat(
   "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss",
   Locale.GERMAN);
parser.setLenient(false);
parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

So, that will parse it as if it were originally in UTC - so when you want to *format* it back to text, you need to do the same thing:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
   "EEE d, yyyy at h:mm:ss tt",
   Locale.US);
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String text = formatter.format(date);
```

Comment: Thanks! Wish our system was initially designed to account for timezones before accepting international dates. This will be somewhat tricky...

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Set `TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin")` as the timezone to `fmt`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.GERMAN);
        fmt.setLenient(false);
        fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
        try {
            Date date = fmt.parse("08 März 2015 02:15:20");
            System.out.println(fmt.format(date));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
08 März 2015 02:15:20
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/X6Ihqa)

In case you want the output with AM/PM marker, the technique will stay the same with an additional step to create another `SimpleDateFormat` instance for output (because the format of the output will be different from the input).

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.GERMAN);
        parser.setLenient(false);
        parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.GERMAN);
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
        try {
            Date date = parser.parse("08 März 2015 02:15:20");
            System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
08 März 2015 02:15:20 AM
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/zMuxhM)

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

Unlike `java.util.Date` which is simply a wrapper around the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT), [`java.time` types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) truly represent a date, a time, a date-time, with and without timezone information.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM uuuu HH:mm:ss", Locale.GERMAN);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM uuuu hh:mm:ss a", Locale.GERMAN);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("08 März 2015 02:15:20", parser);
        System.out.println(parser.format(ldt));
        System.out.println(formatter.format(ldt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
08 März 2015 02:15:20
08 März 2015 02:15:20 AM
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/RQSTW5)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>